# Rails - MySQL auto increment id column type change

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, biginteger, integer-overflow

I have a rails website with lot of models and database tables.
Out of all those, I want to change the :id primary key column to bigint instead of int as it is about to cross the integer int(11) limit on MySQL.

I dont want to use the methods suggested in other posts where they suggest us to do :id => false while creating table and adding a custom column :id specifying size.

I already have a lot of data and i dont want the id column ids also to change as i am using it for some has_many belongs_to relationships and can break all the links.

Please suggest out how i can change_column id from int(11) to bigint without recreating the table and/or loss of data and id values

Answer (score 17):

Do not forget the `auto_increment: true`.

```ruby
class NameOfYourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :table_name, :id, :integer, limit: 8, auto_increment: true
  end

  def down
    change_column :table_name, :id, :integer, auto_increment: true
  end
end
```

Comment: forgetting `auto_increment` = world of pain.

Answer (score 1):

**Give this a try**

Make a migration that looks like this:

```
class NameOfYourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def up
        change_column :table_name, :id, :integer, limit: 8 # <-- makes the column type bigint
    end

    def down
        change_column :table_name, :id, :integer
    end

end
```